# Apache vhost is not working, unless user is logged in via SSH

Tags: bash, apache, .htaccess, ssh, vhosts

Very weird issue incoming.

I have a virtual host defined as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName life.xxx.info
    DocumentRoot /home/xxx/life/app/
    ServerAdmin xxx@gmail.com

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/life-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/life-access_log common
    <Directory /home/ivanatora/life/app/>
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I try to access it, I get

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

with this error in life-error_log:

> [Mon Jul 10 13:09:45 2017] [crit] [client a.b.c.d] (13)Permission denied: /home/xxx/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://life.xxx.info/

File /home/xxx/.htaccess is present and has -rw-rw-r-- permissions.

If I have a logged in user on SSH on that server, this vhost is working perfectly fine. The moment I log out, it starts serving the same error.

Probably it is something very dumb, but I'm baffled by now. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what SSH could have to do with it. Where are you requesting the pages from?

Comment: I don't get it, too. Requests are made from other machines.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an SELinux issue - your configuration file is in a non-standard location, and for security reasons you *really* don't want your web server to be able to read arbitrary paths. You can check this by looking for mentions of `denied` in your audit log, often at /var/log/audit/audit.log.

The *best* way to fix this is to use the standard paths, /etc/httpd for configuration and /var/www for the content.

---

Another possibility is that your setup has some bizarre web server setup stuff in your shell or sshd configuration (I don't know if the latter is even possible). Have a look in ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: I'm not sure if SELinux is running or even if it is installed. `sestatus` and `getenforce` are not present in the system. It is fairly old Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of sounding absolutely bonkers: I'm curious if you are logging in with different user names whereby the hosted site is on an encrypted /home directory. so if you log into as xxx, and /home/xxx is encrypted then it will be unencrypted only if you are logged in -otherwise it's not.